# php code to replace one data with another

Tags: php

I have a project in which there is a form where data is loaded and depending on who has logged in, it automatically loads the name of the company to which it belongs, but now I add a new field where they can write the name of a company x in specific and what I need to know, is if there is a way that when filling that specific name field, it replaces in the database the name of the company to which the logged in person belongs.

I don't know if it's possible.

Thank you very much and I hope you understand what I meant.

Comment: Can you show us some code to see what you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible, but your question is too abstract. Unfortunately it's not possible to write the answer with detail steps. My advice is: try to get a PHP/SQL course to learn some basic stuff. I guess, it would be helpful to know a bit about MVC, Active Record, ORM, CRUD.

But the abstract answer might be like that

1. specify the condition, i.e when the newly added field exist and form has been submitted;
2. find the required row in database (`SELECT * FROM .. WHERE ..`);
3. replace the field with another value;
4. update the database row (`UPDATE table SET column1 = value1 WHERE ..`);

if the DB row does not exist, you should not do steps 2,3,4, you can just do INSERT request to database.